# Convergence of a particular infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How to check for the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{x^n+1}~~\textrm{for}~~x \geq 0~.$$

**My approach:** Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}$.

For $0 \leq x <1 $, we have 
$$\frac{x^n}{x^n+1} \leq x^n$$
and $\sum x^n$ is a geometric series with common ratio $< 1$. So by the **Weierstrass M-test** $\sum \frac{x^n}{x^n+1}$ converges uniformly for $x \in [0 , 1)$.

For $x=1$, we have
$$\sum \frac{1}{2}$$
which diverges.

How to check the convergence for $x > 1$. Any help in getting this done is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x > 1$, we have:
$$
\frac{x^n}{x^n + 1} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x^n}} > \frac{1}{2}
$$
So the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Cauchy's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{x^n+1}}=
x>1$$

Actually this can also prove convergence for $x<1$.